# connection problem with cassandra

Tags: connection, cassandra

I m new to cassandra.I m trying to connect to cassandra bt couldnot connect.
the steps i m following are

1.start the server with command -
 /root/Documents/apache-cassandra-0.6.6/bin/cassandra -f

2.on another terminal i m giving command 
/root/Documents/apache-cassandra-0.6.6/bin/cassandra-cli
which is saying welcome to cassandra cli

3.then i m connecting too cassandra by giving the command
/root/Documents/apache-cassandra-0.6.6/bin/cassandra-cli

but i m getting exception as "Exception connecting to 10.10.10.142/9160 - java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
"

can anyone help me why i m getting such exception.

Comment: I guess the node and the client are not on the same machine? same lan?

Answer (score 4):

This has "nothing" to do with cassandra.

The documentation (regarding NoRouteToHostException) states that:

"***Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the remote host cannot be reached because of an intervening firewall, or if an intermediate router is down.*** "

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider is to add the port 7199 to the firewall or just to test it to see if you can access a 2 node system is to turn off the firewall in linux using " sudo service firewalld stop"

[dse@orion conf]$ dsetool status mars

## DC: Cassandra       Workload: Cassandra       Graph: no

Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--   Address          Load             Effective-Ownership  VNodes                                       Rack         Health [0,1]
UN   10.0.0.165       250.03 KiB       100.00%              1                                            rack1        0.20
UN   10.0.0.20        656.65 KiB       100.00%              256                                          rack1        0.40